# Bookending a node with text with Python's elementtree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, minidom

I'm trying to add text bookends to strings in an XML file. If a string has already been translated before, I want to add a `@@@` and `###` to the beginning and end of the string for further processing. The end result would look like this:

```
<group>
    <seg-source>
        <mrk mid="1" mtype="seg">I have a <g id="157">red</g> pen.</mrk>
    </seg-source>
    <target>
        <mrk mid="1" mtype="seg">@@@J'ai un stylo <g id="157">rouge</g>.###</mrk>
    </target>
</group>
```

I tried before using `xml.minidom` and created a generic text node such as `start_tag = xmldoc.createTextNode(u'@@@')`, and was able to insert/append the nodes as child nodes. (I ultimately gave up using `minidom` for various reasons.)

I was able to convert my script from `minidom` to `elementtree` rather quickly, but I'm getting stuck at this most crucial point. I've read and re-read the documentation but I cannot find anything specific to what I need to do, especially because a lot of the `<mrk>` elements have sub-elements, such as the `<g>` tag in the example. Also, sometimes the first thing in a `<mrk>` node may not be a text element, so I just can't replace the text.

The Python code is pretty basic and as you can see, I have place holders for the bookends.

```
for target in group.iter('target'):
    for mrk in target.iter('mrk'):

        # Adding "@@@" at front of <mrk>
        mrk.insert(0, <magical text-only element here>)

        # Adding "###" to end of <mrk>
        mrk.append(<magical text-only element here>)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

ElementTree treats text in a very non-XML way.  A couple of tricks involved here.  The first is that in `<a>xxx<b>yyy</b>zzz<c>eee</c>rrr</a>`, the way you get to "zzz" is via the `tail` of the `<b>` element.  (I know, XSLT mavens are gnashing their teeth at this.)

Another trick to use is that you can treat ET Elements as if they were a List of child nodes.  So you can use `len(root)` to get how many children it has (ignoring text nodes).

Here's a quick sample program that seemed to run when I tried it. You will probably want to tweak it to your needs, but it should get you going.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlin="""
    <group>
        <mrk>I have a red pen.</mrk>
        <mrk>I have a <g id="157">red</g> pen.</mrk>
        <mrk><xyzzy>Hey!</xyzzy> I have a <g>red</g> pen.</mrk>
        <mrk>There is text <and>this</and></mrk>
    </group>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(xmlin)

for mrk in root:
    if (mrk.text == None):
        mrk.text = "@@@"
    else:
        mrk.text = "@@@" + mrk.text

    # do we have children?
    if (len(mrk) == 0):
        mrk.text = mrk.text + "###"
    else:
        last = mrk[len(mrk)-1]
        if (last.tail == None):
            last.tail = "###"
        else:
            last.tail = last.tail + "###"

print('ET.tostring(root)')
print ET.tostring(root)
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Each XML module has its own weaknesses and strengths, and ElementTree certainly is easier to learn\code than `minidom`. ElementTree, however, adds namespaces when writing out the XML so when inserting text nodes in a 'very XML way', `minidom` was the better solution.